как с помощью selenium и python нажать на кнопку "Ответить" на сайте https://otvet.mail.ru
Допустим у нас есть вопрос - https://otvet.mail.ru/question/239267541
Ниже есть поле ввода ответа на него, когда ввёл туда что-то становится активной синяя кнопка ниже "Ответить". Как на неё нажать? Уже все что можно попробовал и ничего не помогло, то он не может найти этот элемент, то говорит "element not interactable"
Можно какой-нибудь пример простого кода, который на неё сможет нажимать или идею как это сделать
Я пробовал найти кнопку по xpath, но как я понял, он всё время разный из за других ответов на вопрос, хотел также искать кнопку по её class, но он тоже задаётся с помощью js
Помогите пожалуйста

Добавьте в вопрос свои попытки.
